# Powershell call Function with String Variable

Tags: string, function, powershell

```
    function add($n1, $n2){
        return $n1 + $n2
    }

    $num1 = 1
    $num2 = 2

    $operand = "add"

    ########################################################################

    # Given the above scenario, please try to make the next line work:

    # $operand $num1 $num2 -> My ATTEMPT to call function via string variable

    add $num1 $num2 # This is what I am trying to achieve with the above line
```

Please demonstrate how to call the function using the string variable "Operand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the function has been loaded in memory, the 2 most common ways you could invoke your function, when the function's name is stored in a variable (`$operand`), would be to either use the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```
& $operand $num1 $num2 # => 3
```

Or the [dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
. $operand $num1 $num2 # => 3
```

---

You could also use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2) (even though [**not recommended**](https://www.google.com/search?q=invoke+expression+should+be+avoided&oq=invoke+expression+should+be+avoided&aqs=chrome..69i57.7822j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), as long as the expression is wrapped as a *string*:

```
Invoke-Expression "$operand $num1 $num2" # => 3
```

Comment: Thanks!  All 3 worked, went with the "." because it seems "cooler"  :)

Comment: happy to help @colemd1 :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71632577/7571258), here is a different way that uses a [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) of [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$funTable = @{
    add = { param($n1, $n2) $n1 + $n2 }
    sub = { param($n1, $n2) $n1 - $n2 }
}
```

Alternatively you can reference functions (which must have been defined before):

```
$funTable = @{
    add = $function:add
    sub = $function:sub
}
```

Now you can call the functions by string variable like this:

```
$operand = 'add'

& $funTable.$operand $num1 $num2

# Just a different syntax, it's a matter of taste
$funTable.$operand.Invoke( $num1, $num2 )
```

You may use `.` instead of `&`, but in most cases it's not recommended. The difference is that with `.`, any temporary variable defined by the function will leak into the caller's scope, but you normally want such variables to be removed automatically, which is what `&` does.

Advantages of using a `hashtable`:

- Operand functions are logically grouped.
- When the function name is user input, they can't run arbitrary PowerShell code (as would be possible with `& $operand`). They are only allowed to run the functions that you store in `$funTable`. Otherwise they will get an error.